# Is there a way to specify a max timeout for a test?

Tags: unit-test, timeout

I'm trying to write a test around an infinite-loop bug in my Apex code.  I'd love to be basically code something that runs a test for a maximum of X seconds and then asserts a false result if the timeout is reached.  Is that functionality provided natively?

If not, I'll likely just set a local variable to now+Xseconds and run the test until that time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't specify a maximum execution time natively. I've [posted an idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l5CAAAY) that would probably fit your use case. I personally have a class that I insert into potentially long-running code that will periodically check for nearing limits and then throws an exception if the threshold is met.